# Increment nested value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I create players the following way.

```
Players.insert({
  name: name,
  score: 0,
  items: [{'name': 0}, {'name2': 0}...]
});
```

How do I increment the score in a specific player and specific item name (upserting if necessary)?

Sorry for the terrible wording :p

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what fields exactly your planning to increment. Note that there's a list, so ... ?

Comment: Sorry for the terrible wording. I know the _id for the Player, and I want to increment the value corresponding to a known key in the items array in the player record. In pseudo-javascript Players[_id].items[key]++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the answer is - as in life - to simplify the problem by breaking it up.

And to avoid arrays in mongoDB - after all, objects can have as many keys as you like. So, my structure became:

```
{
  "_id": <id>,
  "name": <name>,
  "score": <score>,
  "items": {}
}
```

And to increment the a dynamic key in `items`:

```
// create your update skeleton first
var ud = { $inc: {} };

// fill it in
ud.$inc['item.' + key] = value;

// call it
db.Players.update(player, ud, true);
```

Works a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5465332e6c3e2eeb66ef3683"),
    "name" : "Alex",
    "score" : 0,
    "items" : [
        {
            "food" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

To update you can do:

```
db.Players.update({name: "Alex", "items.food": {$exists : true}}, 
                  {$inc: {score: 1, "items.$.food": 5}})
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5465332e6c3e2eeb66ef3683"),
    "name" : "Alex",
    "score" : 1,
    "items" : [
        {
            "food" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure you can upsert if the document doesn't exist because of the positional operator needed to update the array.